# Should 64bit Compare&Swap (CAS) work on a 32bit machine?  (or 64bit machine?)

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic, compare-and-swap

So I read that in a 32bit machine, one can use the `CAS` operation with aligned 64bit blocks.
Similarly, in a 64bit machine, one can use the `CAS` operation with aligned 128bit blocks.

I'm using a 32bit machine so I tried the following:

```
// sizeof(long long) is 8 bytes, so 64 bits
long long y = 12;
long long z = 12;
long long x = 99;
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&y, z, x);
```

and the `CAS` succeeded changing the value of  `y` to `99`.

But then I tried using a `char array[8];`(which size is 64 bits) instead of a `long long`. And I do:

```
char full[8] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'}; 
char full2[8] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'};   
char full3[8] = {'5', '8', '9', 'G', 'X', '5', '6', 'U'};
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(full, full2, full3);
```

But in this case, the `CAS` fails although `full` and `full2` have exactly the same data. (I also checked that `full` and `full2` where correctly alligned)

So the first time it seems that a `CAS` can be used to 64bit, but the second time it seems it can't. Any ideas why?

### **EDIT**

#### (How about 64bit machines?)

Ok, so the problem was that I was using `char *` in my `CAS` and these were only checked. So the solution was to cast to `long long` or to `uint64_t` which are 64bit values.

But what should I do with a 64bit machine when I need to use 128bit value? `long long` is still 64bit in a 64bit machine and `uint128_t` doesn't seem to exist in C. **So to which type should I cast?** `double long` seems to be 128bit in my 64bit machine, but when doing the following:

```
  double long y = 32432143243214;
  double long z = 32432143243214;

  int x = __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&y, z, 1234321990);
```

I get this compile error
 `error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘__sync_bool_compare_and_swap’`.

Comment: Looks like you are decaying to pointer and not passing the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to deref your pointers and cast.

I tested and this is the only combination that is correct:

```
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap((long long*)full, *(long long *)full2, *(long long *)full3);
```

You need to cast the first param or it will only swap the first char.

Regarding handling 128-bit double long, this is from the gcc 4.1.2 [docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

> The definition given in the Intel documentation allows only for the
>   use of the types int, long, long long as well as their unsigned
>   counterparts. 
>   GCC will allow any integral scalar or pointer type that is 1, 2, 4 or
>   8 bytes in length.

So it would seem you cannot use this function to handle that case.

Comment: You can pass name of array as address - You shouldn't cast it for that. (Size of different pointer types may differ, but we already missed here with UB)

Comment: The compiler checks pointer types as well, and this function is overloaded for several pointer types, so it matters here (e.g. f(int*) and f(char*) will call different functions depending on the cast).  I tried your solution and it only swapped the first char.

Comment: Thanks for answering (once more), could you check my edit (in the question)?

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the value of full2 and full3, not a pointer to it. Also, you should be care about the alignment.

```
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap((long long*)full,*(long long*)full2,*(long long*)full3);
```

(Of course, this is not portable. If you want portability, use `uint64_t` instead of `long long`)

Comment: __sync_bool_compare_and_swap/CMPXCHG*B itself isn't something portable.

Comment: I tested it and this yields an incorrect output: 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you check my edit (in the question)?

Comment: Since you changed your answer to match mine, would you consider adding something original or deleting it to prevent noise?  For the comment's sake, the original answer you posted was __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(full,*(long long*)full2,*(long long*)full3), without casting the first pointer.

Comment: Yes, but my initial comment, which users see before the edit history, would be confusing, without my second comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a `char *` to `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`. Assuming your char arrays (all three of them!) are properly aligned to 64 bits (if they're allocated in the way you show, they may not be - use `malloc`!), try casting to `(long long *)` before passing to `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`. Failing that, use inline assembler and invoke `CMPXCHG8B` directly.

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you check my edit (in the question)?

Comment: @FookoR., open a new question for the 128-bit CAS question, it has a very different answer (toss me a link to it once you do)